# Plot function X->R with restricted domain where X={(x,y) | 2*x^2+y^2 < 1}

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, domain

To eleborate my question let f be the function f(x,y)=x^2+y^2. Now i only want to plot the function
f: X -> R where X={(x,y) | 2*x^2+y^2<1}
but i want to restrict the domain such that only the inner part of the function gets drawn. Here is my code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\begin{axis}[axis lines=center,
axis on top,
xtick=\empty,
ytick=\empty,
ztick=\empty,
xrange=-2:2,
yrange=-2:2
]
% function
\addplot3[domain=-2:2,y domain=-2:2,colormap/viridis,surf,opacity=0.5]
%shader=interp für optional Linien weg
{x^2+y^2};
% Line on the function
\addplot3[color=black,
samples=40,
domain=0:2*pi,
line width=1.0pt]
({2*cos(deg(x))}, 
{sin(deg(x))}, 
{(2*cos(deg(x)))^2+sin(deg(x))^2});
% Line on bottom
\addplot3[dashed,
samples=40,
domain=0:2*pi]
({2*cos(deg(x))}, 
{sin(deg(x))}, 
{0});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The resulting Image is:

[image]

Now how do i make it such that only the "inner" part inside of the black line gets drawn. (Sorry for bad english i'm german)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome! I'd just use polar coordinates.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\begin{axis}[axis lines=center,
axis on top,
xtick=\empty,
ytick=\empty,
ztick=\empty,
xrange=-2:2,
yrange=-2:2
]
\begin{scope}
\addplot3[domain=0:1,y domain=0:2*pi,colormap/viridis,surf,opacity=0.5,
samples=5,samples y=40,
] %-0.2 just to avoid gaps
%shader=interp für optional Linien weg
({2*x*cos(deg(y))},{x*sin(deg(y))},{(2*x*cos(deg(y)))^2+(x*sin(deg(y)))^2});
\end{scope}
% Line on the function
\addplot3[color=black,
samples=40,
domain=0:2*pi,
line width=1.0pt]
({2*cos(deg(x))}, 
{sin(deg(x))}, 
{(2*cos(deg(x)))^2+(sin(deg(x)))^2});
% Line on bottom
\addplot3[dashed,
samples=40,
domain=0:2*pi,smooth]
({2*cos(deg(x))}, 
{sin(deg(x))}, 
{0});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You *can* stick to Cartesian coordinates use `/pgfplots/restrict expr to domain` (such as `restrict expr to domain={x^2/4+y^2}{0:1}` for your case). BTW, your contour does not enclose `{(x,y) | 2*x^2+y^2<1}`. It encloses `{(x,y) | x^2/4+y^2<1}`. However, according to my experience, this does not lead to very nice results for these kinds of plots because the boundaries get "pixelated".

Comment: Thank you very much :) I would have never come up with the idea of using polar coordinates for such a problem. You saved my day!

Comment: @LukasSchanz You are welcome! (Unfortunately the other tricks like clip do not work easily for this problem.)